# Сервис для получения ссылки на чистый текст

Tags: text

Есть ли сервисы, желательно с api, которые позволяют создать текст онлайн, и хранить его неограниченное количество времени в виде текстого файла на хостинге?
Например чтобы я мог сделать запрос на такой сервис, указав в виде параметра нужный текст и сразу получить ссылку на чистый файл с этим текстом.

Comment: можете попробовать google drive или что-то в этом роде. Там не только текст, но вы можете хранить там только текст), api есть на большинстве подобных.

Comment: Не слышал о таком